# Сетевые интерфейсы люнекс

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте скажите пожалуйста как я могу сделать переадресацию трафика с впн сервера outline на клиента wineguard. Когда я подключаю сервер A к серверу B wineguard то у меня пропадает ssh подключение. Резюмируя мне надо сделать прокси сервер между клиентом и vpn wireguard. Тоесть подключился по outline а на выходе wineguard. Я так понимаю на прокси сервере я запускаю сервер outline и клиента wireguard и как то должен перенаправлять трафик с одного сетевого интерфейса на другой и обратно при этом я должен получать доступ по ssh через ip прокси сервера. Подскажите что именно изучить чтоб разобраться в теме. Или вообще такой подход возможен или нет